# Get last Sunday within a range of two dates (GMT, DST)

Tags: php, datetime, date, dst, gmt

I'm trying to get the last Sunday between two week numbers - in order to avoid DST.

IN ORDER WORDS: Start a range of time - from the last Sunday in March to the last Sunday in October.

This is my code:

```
   $heloo = gmdate('U');
   if ( (date("W", $heloo) >= 12) 
       && (date("W", $heloo) <= 43)
       && (date("N", $heloo) == 7) ) {
    echo "YES Day is: ".date("N", $heloo). "<br />
           Week is: ". date("W", $heloo);
  } else { 
  echo "NO Day is: ".date("N", $heloo). "<br />Week is: ". date("W", $heloo); 
 }
```

The weeks seems to work fine but the days doesn't work at all. Could you please point me to the right direction or advice where to get some help?

:-)

Comment: Post your inputs and format of expected output. This is easy task :) some examples.

Comment: I don't understand... that if statement really translates to `date("W", $heloo) == 12 && date("N", $heloo) == 7`

Comment: Also, I can't connect the dots between your code, your description and your question in subject. Be more specific please.

Comment: Sorry to confuse... I wanted to create a range of days starting from the last Sunday of march to the last Sunday of October. Is that possible? I have editted the code. Please have a look now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this easy piece of code:

```
  function rangeSundays($year, $month_start, $month_end) {
    $res = array();
    for ($i = $month_start; $i <= $month_end; $i++) {
      $dt = strtotime('last sunday of this month', strtotime("$year-$i-1"));
      $res[] = date('Y-m-d', $dt);
      } 
    return $res;
    }
```

So, use it this way

```
$date_array = rangeSundays(2011, 3, 10); // year, start month, end month
print_r($date_array);
```

Output

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 2011-03-27
        [1] => 2011-04-24
        [2] => 2011-05-29
        [3] => 2011-06-26
        [4] => 2011-07-31
        [5] => 2011-08-28
        [6] => 2011-09-25
        [7] => 2011-10-30
    )
```

Also, if default time zone is not set in your php config (php.ini) add something like this at start of your script to avoid throwing warnings in PHP.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // or any other time zone
```

To print this result out to screen use

```
$date_array = rangeSundays(2011, 3, 10);
foreach($date_array as $x) {
  echo "$x<br/>";
  }
```

---

**If you want to do it without using function**

```
$year = 2011; // or which year you want
$month_start = 3; // for starting month; March in this case
$month_end = 10; // for ending month; October in this case

$res = array();
for ($i = $month_start; $i <= $month_end; $i++) {
  $dt = strtotime('last sunday of this month', strtotime("$year-$i-1"));
  $res[] = date('Y-m-d', $dt);
  }

foreach($res as $sunday) {
  echo "$sunday<br />";
  }
```

**Output**

```
2011-03-27
2011-04-24
2011-05-29
2011-06-26
2011-07-31
2011-08-28
2011-09-25
2011-10-30
```

Note: DST doesn't affect dates in this case.

Your code looks like unnecessary complication :)

Comment: I'm not really good with functions. is it possible to write the code as generic PHP? I have been struggling, trying to input my data into your function. I have a single data to work on.